# shell commands in an app

Tags: android, adb

I want to use some linux commands in an android app using the

```
Process proc= runtime.getruntime().exec(".......")
```

does this work without conflict on an all android devices by default? the app runs perfectly on my phone, but i am in doubt if it will run all others because dumpsys seemed to have some issues on certain phones. 
Any info that will help understand this detail would be great!

what about ADB commands like pull? is it ok to use them in an app?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the RootTools library.

http://code.google.com/p/roottools/

```
CommandCapture commands = new CommandCapture(0, /* ls -l */);
try {
    RootTools.getShell(true).add(commands).waitForFinish();
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // ...
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: my point is that i want to use certain commands on non rooted devices, as a part of an app...is that ok?

Comment: Yes it is. `RootTools.getShell(true)` gets a root shell, `RootTools.getShell(false)` gets a regular shell.